# Any ZXY satellite basemaps covering New Zealand at zoom 19?

Tags: carto, basemap, new-zealand, zxy

I need a good satellite base map to use with CartoDB.  It has to cover all of New Zealand at zoom 19, [edit:] and be as recent as possible so we can show recently-built properties.  **It doesn't have to be free.** (In fact, we're rather expecting to have to pay for it.)

I'm using ArcGIS's `http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}` at the moment, and while it's good at zoom 19 in some places...

[image: good at zoom 19]

... in other places it only goes to 18, and it can get pretty grainy...

[image: poor at zoom 18]

Comment: you can use bing maps (aerial and oblique) https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?&ty=30&q=new%20zealand&satid=id.sid%3a6517d967-9362-4c0d-83d2-cf369fa5fcda&vdpid=183&mb=-29.831572~148.488083~-50.757644~-161.150589&tt=New%20Zealand&tsts0=%2526ty%253d30%2526q%253dnew%252520zealand%2526satid%253did.sid%25253a6517d967-9362-4c0d-83d2-cf369fa5fcda%2526vdpid%253d183%2526mb%253d-29.831572~148.488083~-50.757644~-161.150589&tstt0=New%20Zealand&cp=83hwwkzjy0f5&lvl=19&style=b&ftst=0&ftics=False&v=2&sV=1&form=S00027 source https://gist.github.com/javisantana/c20601e782aca32fc863

Answer (score 3):

A free one is here: https://data.linz.govt.nz/set/2-nz-aerial-imagery/

The WMTS endpoint is `http://tiles-{s}.data-cdn.linz.govt.nz/services;key=YOUR_API_TOKEN/tiles/v4/set=2/EPSG:3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

I use it in this map: https://spatialparalysis.xyz/national-crash-statistics/ (zoom in).

It doesn't have complete coverage, but it's reasonable over all cities and most towns. There are probably paid alternatives, but I don't know about them. I don't think there is 100% coverage, otherwise LINZ (the central government body linked to above) would probably already provide it.

Some places are still likely to be grainy. AFAIK, the actual aerial imagery in NZ is provided by regional and local government, who have different priorities and resources.

Comment: thanks for this.  Yes, it's quite good.  It seems to be a bit out-of-date for my purposes.  We're in real estate, so new builds have to show up quite quickly.  Sorry, I didn't originally mention that in my question.

Comment: just to clarify - YOUR_API_TOKEN - is that my Carto API token?  It looks like it's being passed to LINZ, which seems odd.  Do you know why LINZ need it?

Comment: LINZ is using the Koordinates platform, e.g. http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/unlimited/10104384/Kiwi-tech-firm-mapping-out-strong-future I suppose it tracks usage. It's the API token you get from registering with the LINZ Data Service at https://data.linz.govt.nz